# How do I force Terraform, Service Principals, and Service Connections to automatically scope to my Subscription Ownership only given MS Graph API?

Tags: terraform, azure-devops, role-based-access-control

AAD Graph API has now been fully deprecated. Terraform, Service Principals, and Service Connections now use the MS Graph API.

My company has given me my own Visual Studio Subscription and I have my own organization in DevOps. I am Owner in both.

Before, under the old AAD Graph API, I could programmatically create service principals or alter their permissions on the fly, either through code or Terraform, etc. For example, I could use this Terraform code to create a service principal or change the role of another one:

```
## These are in my resource group
...
resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.example.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}
...
...
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "kubweb_to_acr" {
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kubweb.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
}
```

Even though I am Owner in my Subscription, this no longer works. When I try to create SPs programmatically, like I used to, I get errors like this [because of MS Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors):

```
Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '3520c717-e1cc-4d0b-b021-2f93a1b05d80' with object id '3520c717-e1cc-4d0b-b021-2f93a1b05d80' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write
```

and

```
ApplicationsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData
│ error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the
│ operation.
```

Each time I create an SP or a Service Connection in DevOps, I scope it to my Subscription. But, I keep getting errors saying that I don't have permission create it or modify it. I own it! I should have permissions!

Anway, it always gets created under the umbrella of my Parent Company's Active Directory. I can't modify it va MSGraph API Permissions. "Grant Admin Consent" is always greyed out.

What do I need to do, what role do I need applied, or how do I restructure programmatically creating my SP, MSIs, and Service connections so they are scoped to my subscription where I have full control over them again?